# Quartz 3.0 and above not working with Windows Service

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services, quartz.net

I have a Windows service that works fine with Quartz 2.6. Now I want to call some API's So I researched a bit and got to know that Quartz3.0 and above have support for `Async/Await`. But With Quartz 3.0 my Execute Function is not getting called.

**Main Class**

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myService = new Service1();
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            string parameter = string.Concat(args);
            switch (parameter)
            {
                case "--install":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
                case "--uninstall":
                    ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                    break;
            }
            #if DEBUG
                 myService.Start();
            #endif

        }
        else
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { myService };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        TestDemoJob1().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }


    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStop.txt");
    }

    public void Start()
    {

        OnStart(new string[0]);
    }
    public static async Task TestDemoJob1()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler;
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        scheduler.Start().Wait();
        int ScheduleIntervalInMinute = 10;//job will run every minute
        JobKey jobKey = JobKey.Create("DemoJob1");
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DemoJob1>().WithIdentity(jobKey).Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobTrigger")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(ScheduleIntervalInMinute).RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

**Job Class**

```
public class DemoJob1 : IJob
{
    public DemoJob1()
    {
    }
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
       //Some Async Task
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

}
```

If I try to run the same application in Console Application this works. But If I try to run it with Windows Service application. The Execute function never gets executed. Any help would be appreciated. I am stuck in this for the last 3 hours or so. Already tried many ways but none of them are working.

Comment: Have you tried adding logging to know what exactly is happening and not happening?

Comment: Yes I tried to make a text file. Its not created.

Comment: Put Some Logging. Have you used log4net prior? you can use it for easy logging. Also put some try catch for logging purpose

Comment: I am facing same problem, have you solved?

Comment: @HowardHee I Cant remember If I was able to solve it or not.